# How to create sankey diagram with gradient color links in Plotly?

Tags: html, svg, plotly, plotly-python, sankey-diagram

Is there a way to make the links in a Plotly Sankey diagram have a color gradient between the source node color and the end node color? This image is taken from a [page](https://observablehq.com/@d3/sankey-diagram) linked by the [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/) documentation.

I have seen some [discussion](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3261) on GitHub about this feature in Plotly but they never said if it was actually implemented or not. Ideally the result should still be a vector graphic displayable in a HTML file.

[image: Sankey plot with colored links]

Comment: have you solved this issue? I'm interested in doing the same.

Comment: @AEndrs unfortunately not using plotly. People in the github discussion I linked earlier said to try d3-sankey.